# email_verified = false in ID token from Google

Tags: jwt, google-authentication, google-oauth

I use [Google ID tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) to sign in users to my webservice. As part of validating the token it receives from Google, the webservice checks that `email_verified = true` in the token's payload.

Some of my users [signed up for a Google-account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp) with their non-Gmail, non-Google Apps email address. They did click the link in the email that Google sent them after sign-up, to verify their email address.

When those users try to login to my webservice, I get `email_verified = false` in the token's payload.

What does this mean and can/ should I ignore this in validating the token?

Comment: If you are validating that the users have a valid account / email address then no you probably shouldn't ignore it.   How are you achieving this login?  I haven't tried it but if email_verified returns as part of the profile scopes and the users in question don't have Google+ accounts I wonder if it will even return.

Comment: If the email was verified by the user then we should be returning true in that claim. We need to look into this. If possible can you send me the email address of the user through my G+ profile?

Comment: @nvnagr I've sent you two examples via G+

Comment: @Rob I know it's been a while but I have a similar issue were some long-time "Google account" members also get an unverified status when they try to sign-up. I have now bypassed this as it seems strange, but have you maybe found why some Google accounts have this set as false? Thanks in advance

Comment: This article explains things further: https://jpassing.com/2021/01/27/what-does-the-email_verified-claim-indicate-in-google-idtokens/ - but still, it also says that only edge cases would have Google accounts set as false..

Comment: @OwenFar No, sorry, I have not found an answer..

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different [ways](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) in which you can validate the integrity of the ID token on the server side:

1. "Manually" - constantly download Google's public keys, verify signature and then each and every field, including the `iss` one; the main advantage (albeit a small one in my opinion) I see here is that you can minimize the number of requests sent to Google.
2. "Automatically" - do a GET on Google's endpoint to verify this token
   `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={0}`
3. Using a Google API Client Library - like the [official one](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client).

Here's how this could look:

```cs
private const string GoogleApiTokenInfoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={0}";

public ProviderUserDetails GetUserDetails(string providerToken)
{
    var httpClient = new MonitoredHttpClient();
    var requestUri = new Uri(string.Format(GoogleApiTokenInfoUrl, providerToken));

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage;
    try
    {
        httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri).Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }

    if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var response = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var googleApiTokenInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleApiTokenInfo>(response);

    if (!SupportedClientsIds.Contains(googleApiTokenInfo.aud))
    {
        Log.WarnFormat("Google API Token Info aud field ({0}) not containing the required client id", googleApiTokenInfo.aud);
        return null;
    }

    return new ProviderUserDetails
    {
        Email = googleApiTokenInfo.email,
        FirstName = googleApiTokenInfo.given_name,
        LastName = googleApiTokenInfo.family_name,
        Locale = googleApiTokenInfo.locale,
        Name = googleApiTokenInfo.name,
        ProviderUserId = googleApiTokenInfo.sub
    };
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the second option, that's a great tip! I had the first option in place. This doesn't answer the issue though: as email_verified is still false in the JWT Google issues and my question is whether I should accept that or not

Comment: Hi Alexandru,  tokeninfo endpoint is there to help with debugging.  id_token was created to make it easy for the server to validate it without making a network call that will add to the delay.  Your suggestion creates a security issue. The very important part of the id token validation is to validate that the token was meant for your server (the audience field) . By calling the tokeninfo, you only get to know that it was a valid id_token but unless you check on the audience, you'll create a security issue. The best option is to use a library. using tokeninfo endpoint should be avoided.

Comment: Hi @nvnagr, regarding the validation of the `aud` field, if you look closely, you can see on that page that Google also clearly states this - and I also do it in the provided code sample.

Comment: @Rob unless you can prove that the tokeinfo endpoint responds with a `HttpStatusCode 200 OK` even when the email is not verified (false), I don't think there's any issue